# Htaccess redirect without url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a little problem in hands.

I am setting up a domain that as 3 languages, example.com for principal domain, en.(...) for english and de.(...) for germany.
Usually I only redirect the httpdocs from the subdomains to the main with ln -S because all languages executes the same code, the difference is matched from php and mysql.

My new host don't provide any ssh connection so I have to use a different approach on this.

It was told to me that it can be done by .htaccess but I already tried a lot of things but only can redirect, changing the url and that's not possible, it have to keep the same, the contents yes, will be from another domain. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should looks like the one you're searching for :

**www.domain.en .htaccess**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**www.domain.de .htaccess**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You'll propably adapt the `http://www.domain.com/lang/$1` part to your needs.

---

**EDIT**

Following your comment, this is a code for subdomains redirections :

**domain.com .htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/en/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^de\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/de/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @zessx but it's not really that. That code change the url also, and it's not intended, I just want to show the content of another page and maintain en.example.com/de.example.com.

Comment: It keeps doing the redirect. I already checked with phpinfo that mod_proxy is active. But it's almost that